# Error when running flutter pub run zoom:unzip_zoom_sdk

Tags: flutter

I am using zoom: ^1.0.3+1 on my flutter project but aevery time I try to run `flutter pub run zoom:unzip_zoom_sdk`, I get this error:

> Download https://www.dropbox.com/s/44rv7hgvqbgm7j7/MobileRTC?dl=1 to C:/src/skills/skillmonga/.dart_tool/pub/bin/zoom/unzip_zoom_sdk.dart-2.15.1.snapshot/ios/MobileRTC.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/MobileRTC.framework/MobileRTC
>
> Unhandled exception:
>
> FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:/src/skills/skillmonga/.dart_tool/pub/bin/zoom/unzip_zoom_sdk.dart-2.15.1.snapshot/ios/MobileRTC.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/MobileRTC.framework/MobileRTC' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified., errno = 3)
>
> #0      _File.open. (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
>
> pub finished with exit code 255

I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

- Upgrade the zoom package to `1.0.3+2` or `1.0.3+3`

As per the [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/zoom/changelog#1032), the developer has outlined that the bug has been fixed using the above-mentioned versions.